# Spark - Group by HAVING with dataframe syntax?

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

What's the syntax for using a groupby-having in Spark without an sql/hiveContext? I know I can do

```
DataFrame df = some_df
df.registreTempTable("df");    
df1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df GROUP BY col1 HAVING some stuff")
```

but how do I do it with a syntax like

```
df.select(df.col("*")).groupBy(df.col("col1")).having("some stuff")
```

This `.having()` does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't exist. You express the same logic with `agg` followed by `where`:

```
df.groupBy(someExpr).agg(somAgg).where(somePredicate)
```

Answer (score 28):

Say for example if I want to find products in each category, having fees less than 3200 and their count must not be less than 10:

- SQL query:

```
sqlContext.sql("select Category,count(*) as 
count from hadoopexam where HadoopExamFee<3200  
group by Category having count>10")
```

- DataFrames API (Pyspark)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.filter(df.HadoopExamFee<3200)
  .groupBy('Category')
  .agg(count('Category').alias('count'))
  .filter(col('count')>10)
```

Comment: It is not working cause count cannot be found in filter()

Comment: @stanPeng - you likely forgot to run 'from pyspark.sql.functions import *' statement; snippet worked for me

Comment: I had only 'col' function in my import, and it didn`t work. but when I put a '*' it works. Do you know which other SQL functions I have to include in my import besides 'col'?

Comment: @GlibMartynenko, Hi, you need to import count function also(which is coming inside agg) along with col

Comment: You can use from pyspark.sql.functions import count