# Creating a new dataframe with groupBy and filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following is my `dataframe`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (0, 1),
  (0, 2),
  (0, 5),
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 5),
  (2, 1),
  (2, 2)
], ["id", "product"])
```

I need to do a `groupBy` of `id` and collect all the items as shown below, but I need to check the product count and if it is less than 2, that should not be there it collected items.

For example, product 3 is repeated only once, i.e. count of 3 is 1, which is less than 2, so it should not be available in following dataframe. Looks like I need to do two `groupBy`s:

Expected output:

```
+---+------------+
| id|       items|
+---+------------+
|  0|   [1, 2, 5]|
|  1|   [1, 2, 5]|
|  2|      [1, 2]|
+---+------------+
```

Comment: which module/library/package is spark.createdataframe function found in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think indeed two `groupBy`'s is a decent solution, you can use a `leftsemi` join after the first `groupBy` to filter your intial `DataFrame`. Working example solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, 1),
(0, 2),
(0, 5),
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 5),
(2, 1),
(2, 2)
], ["id", "product"])

df = df\
.join(df.groupBy('product').count().filter(F.col('count')>=2),'product','leftsemi').distinct()\
.orderBy(F.col('id'),F.col('product'))\
.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('product').alias('product'))

df.show()
```

Where the `orderBy` clause is optional, only if you care about the ordering in the result. Output:

```
+---+---------+
| id|  product|
+---+---------+
|  0|[1, 2, 5]|
|  1|[1, 2, 5]|
|  2|   [1, 2]|
+---+---------+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a `Window` to get the count for each product and use that to `filter` before the `groupBy()`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn('count', f.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('product')))\
    .where('count > 1')\
    .groupBy('id')\
    .agg(f.collect_list('product').alias('items'))\
    .show()
#+---+---------+
#| id|    items|
#+---+---------+
#|  0|[5, 1, 2]|
#|  1|[5, 1, 2]|
#|  2|   [1, 2]|
#+---+---------+
```

Unfortunately [the `HAVING` statement does not exist in spark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848866/spark-group-by-having-with-dataframe-syntax).