# How to get the COUNT of emails for each id in Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use this query in SQL to get return how many user_id's have more than one email.  How would I write this same query against a users DataFrame in Scala? also how would I be able to return to exact emails for each user_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM Users
Group by user_id
Having count(DISTINCT email) > 1
```

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848866/spark-group-by-having-with-dataframe-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a dataframe of users. In spark, one could create a sample of such a dataframe like this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("me", "contact@me.com"),
             ("me", "me@company.com"),
             ("you", "you@company.com")).toDF("user_id", "email")
df.show()

+-------+---------------+
|user_id|          email|
+-------+---------------+
|     me| contact@me.com|
|     me| me@company.com|
|    you|you@company.com|
+-------+---------------+
```

Now, the logic would be very similar as the one you have in SQL:

```scala
df.groupBy("user_id")
  .agg(countDistinct("email") as "count")
  .where('count > 1)
  .show()

+-------+-----+
|user_id|count|
+-------+-----+
|     me|    2|
+-------+-----+
```

Then you can add a `.drop("count")` or a `.select("user_id")` to only keep users.

Note that **there is no `having` clause in spark**. Once you have called `agg` to aggregate your dataframe by user, you have a regular dataframe on which you can call any transformation function, such as a filter on the `count` column here.